# How to use parameterized snowflake UDF in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, snowflake-connector

I have a user defined function in snowflake with arguments and returns a table.
function orders_for_product(varchar,varchar,datetime,datetime)

I want to use this function in Power BI.

What I tried before is:
Creating a view in snowflake. But passing parameters was not possible in view.
As the dataset has many aggregations and date filters on different date columns present in different CTE's, applying filters on PowerBI desktop is giving unexpected output.

The major challenge is that the dataset has to be used in PowerBI Report Builder with parameters values entered by users.

Comment: You  can't used parameterised sources like that in Power BI. You can with "paginated reports" though.

Comment: Prior to Power BI, there was SSRS, which in Power BI is called "paginated reports". You would very commonly use a parameterised stored procedure as it's data source.